# How to center canvas in html5

Tags: html, canvas, css, resize

I've been searching for a solution for a while now, but haven't found anything. Maybe it's just my search terms.
Well, I'm trying to make the canvas center according to the size of the browser window. The canvas is 800x600.
And if the window gets below 800x600, it should resize as well(but that's not very important at the moment)

Comment: How do I tell it to make a full page canvas without giving dimensions and without having scrollbars when resizing?

Comment: Don't do it in HTML .. do it with javascript, use stuff like appendChild or something and set width and height to window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

Answer (score 222):

Give the canvas the following css style properties:

```
canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
}
```

---

**Edit**

Since this answer is quite popular, let me add a little bit more details.

The above properties will **horizontally** center the canvas, div or whatever other node you have relative to it's parent. There is no need to change the top or bottom margins and paddings. You specify a width and let the browser fill the remaining space with the auto margins.

However, if you want to type less, you could use whatever css shorthand properties you wish, such as

```
canvas {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Centering the canvas **vertically** requires a different approach however. You need to use absolute positioning, and specify both the width and the height. Then set the left, right, top and bottom properties to 0 and let the browser fill the remaining space with the auto margins.

```
canvas {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The canvas will center itself based on the first parent element that has `position` set to `relative` or `absolute`, or the body if none is found.

Another approach would be to use `display: flex`, that is available in IE11

Also, make sure you use a recent doctype such as xhtml or html 5.

Comment: display: block; and margin:0 auto 0 auto; is enough also. Thx!

Comment: For vertically centering a canvas, you don't need to put the width and the height in, as long as you specify it in the HTML. On chrome, anyway.

Comment: Width and height can be specified in css or html. But css is the recommended way since all presentation logic should go there.

Comment: It is centering the canvas but if there is image drawn on the canvas, it is stretching. Can you center the canvas without stretching the image

Comment: Setting height and width in inline styles on the canvas element messed up the sizes of my drawn images and such. Just a caveat that will hopefully save someone some frustration.

Answer (score 57):

You can give your canvas the ff CSS properties:

```
#myCanvas
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? This approach does not appear to work

Comment: This works for horizontal centering, but not vertical centering.

Answer (score 28):

To center the canvas element horizontally, you must specify it as a block level and leave its left and right margin properties to the browser:

```
canvas{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

If you wanted to center it vertically, the canvas element needs to be absolutely positioned:

```
canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);              
}
```

If you wanted to center it horizontally and vertically, do:

```
canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);               
}
```

For more info visit: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 20):

Just center the div in HTML:

```
  #test {
     width: 100px;
     height:100px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }


<div id="test">
   <canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Just change the height and width to whatever and you've got a centered div

http://jsfiddle.net/BVghc/2/

Comment: Lucky me, I needed this soon after you posted it. :)

Comment: This does not work if the canvas is smaller than the container.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use Flexbox, however the `canvas` element must be inside a `div`, just applying it to the `canvas` element will not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas width="150" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.canvas-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answers only work if your canvas is the same width as the container.

This works regardless:

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `text-align: center;` to the **parent tag** of `<canvas>`. That's it.

**Example:**

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <canvas width="300" height="300">
        <!--your canvas code -->
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: this is simple then using css

Comment: simplest and solved my problem as well. best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.text-center{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="text-center">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, as I have pictures with many different widths which I load only with height info. Setting a width allows the browser to stretch and squeeze the picture. I solve the problem by having the text line just before the image_tag line centred (also getting rid of float: left;). I would have liked the text to be left aligned, but this is a minor inconvienence, that I can tolerate.

Answer (score 0):

Using grid?

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); 
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

canvas {
  height: 80vh; 
  width: 80vw; 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
        <canvas></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```