# html center a canvas inside a div without stretching the canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have a html like:

```css
.image-detail {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
.image-detail-canvas {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-detail">
  <canvas class="image-detail-canvas" id="image-canvas">

  </canvas>
</div>
```

It is centering the canvas but the canvas is stretching.

I dont want the canvas to be stretched.

I want it to be centered without stretching. If the canvas is horizontal center it horizontally and if vertical then so on.

Comment: Yours is an often asked question. If you want to avoid stretching while resizing with CSS then let the canvas **resize proportionally** by setting either-but-not-both of width & height. Alternatively, set the canvas element width & height and no pixels will be stretched. Again, this is an often asked question on Stackoverflow so search Stackoverflow for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Remove `Position: absolute;` and `translate`

Add some width to your `canvas` and put `margin: 0 auto;`, Hope that helps.

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.image-detail-canvas {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-detail">
  <canvas class="image-detail-canvas" id="image-canvas" width="100" height="100">

  </canvas>
</div>
```

Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782251/5336321

Comment: This stretches the canvas...

Comment: @Kaiido check the answer now!

Comment: I want to center it horizontally and vertically.. I guess it is centering only horizontally not vertically

Comment: @aryan This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7782251/5336321

Comment: My above code was also centering the cavas but the thing was it was stretching the canvas. I have image in this canvas and it is stretching...

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to change `position` to `absolute`, plus add width/height definitions to all parent elements (also `html` and `body`):

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0;
}
.image-detail {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
}
.image-detail-canvas {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-detail">
  <canvas class="image-detail-canvas" id="image-canvas" width="100" height="100">

  </canvas>
</div>
```