# Why does text-align have an effect on canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have multiple canvases layered over eachother, basically I'm making a paint app that has history and delete. The canvases are not the same width as the parent div.

I was banging my head on the desk trying to center my canvas within the div until I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30998428/8278589), which is pretty much the lowest voted question.

In short:

> The above answers only work if your canvas is the same width as the container.
>
> This works regardless:

```
#container {
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: center;
}
```

If I comment out text-align my canvases go off center.

**Q:** How does this make any sense and why does text-align have an effect on canvas elements?

There are some weird quirks about CSS that I've learned in similar ways and use quite often. I think understanding this will be another tool in the chest to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas` is a by default an inline element (just like `img`, `input`, etc.) so it is displayed inside the text flow. Run the example below to see an example.

Give the canvas `display: block` to make it a block element.

```html
<p>This is a longer text with inline elements such as canvas <canvas style="width: 1em; height: 1em; border: 1px solid red;"></canvas>, image <img src="http://lorempixel.com/20/20/" /> and an <input type="button" value="input" /> element.</p>

<p>Give the canvas <code>display: block</code>, like this one <canvas style="width: 1em; height: 1em; border: 1px solid red; display: block"></canvas>, so that it becomes an block element.</p>
```